# Java : Is the get method of an Arraylist cached?

Tags: java, performance, memory, arraylist, get

Does the Arraylist object store the last requested value in memory to access it faster the next time? Or do I need to do this myself?

Or more concretely, in terms of performance, is it better to do this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++){
    int value = myArray.get(i);

    int result = value + 2 * value - 5 / value;
}
```

Instead of doing this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++)
    int result = myArray.get(i) + 2 * myArray.get(i) - 5 / myArray.get(i);
```

Comment: In terms of performance, it doesn't matter one bit.

Comment: @Kayaman even with large ArrayLists?

Comment: It's the same thing you are just declaring an additional variable in first one. but it's clearer

Comment: Considering that `ArrayList` is not a thread-safe collection and the loop is tight, it would be in the processor cache anyway.

Comment: Consider using enhanced for loop (though I'm not sure if your original code makes sense because it always reassigns the 'result' without using the value):

for (int value : myArray) {
   int result = value + 2 * value - 5 / value;
}

In Java8 you can make it even more concise with lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance, it doesn't matter one bit. No, `ArrayList` doesn't cache anything, although the JITted end result could be a different issue.

If you're wondering which version to use, use the first one. It's clearer.

Comment: " it doesn't matter one bit." not completely true, the second option will use three calls, and three times auto-unboxing, which are more expensive then accessing a variable. I doubt if you notice it though..

Comment: It doesn't matter because it's a useless micro optimization. It also doesn't matter because JIT will most likely turn that into something a lot more efficient than what it looks like in the question.

Comment: You don't know when JIT kicks in, and will the JIT know that it potentially could optimize three calls to an arraylist into a single one? How does the JIT know which calls are guaranteed to return the *same object* on consecutive calls?

Comment: That goes beyond the scope of this question. Let's just say that JIT is a lot smarter than many of the people asking questions.

Comment: "You don't know when JIT kicks in", and I don't need to. Although if I'm interested, I can tune it. "will the JIT know that it potentially could optimize three calls to an arraylist into a single one?", probably, it does a lot more complex things, so that would be hardly anything special. "How does the JIT know which calls are guaranteed to return the same object on consecutive calls?", it analyzes the code being run of course. How else could it optimize efficiently? You give JIT far less credit than it deserves (and manual micro-optimization far more than it deserves).

Comment: Oh no, very time I read some super fancy thing about the JIT I'm really amazed at how smart it has become and what wonderful things it can do. Just curious in how it would handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer your (first) question yourself by looking into the actual source:

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

So: No, there is no caching taking place but you can also see that there is no much of an impact in terms of performance because the `get` method is essentially just an access to an array.

But it's still good to avoid multiple calls for some reasons:

- `int result = value + 2 * value - 5 / value` is easier to understand (i.e. realizing that you use the same value three times in your calculation)
- If you later decide to change the underlying list (e.g. to a LinkedList) you might end up with an impact on performance and then have to change your code to get around it.
- As long as you don't synchronize the access to the list, repeated calls of `get(index)` might actually return different values if between two calls a call of `set(index, value)` has taken place (even in small souce blocks like this, it's possible to happen - BTST)

The second point has also a consequence in terms of how to access all values of a list, that leads to the decision to avoid `list.get(i)` altogether if you're going to iterate over all elements in a list. In that case it's better to use the `Iterator` or streams:

You code would then look like this:

```
Iterator it = myArray.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    int value = it.next();

    int result = value + 2 * value - 5 / value;
}
```

`LinkedList` is very slow when trying to access elements in it by specific index but can iteratre quite fast from one element to the next, so the `Iterator` returned by `LinkedList` makes use of that while the `Iterator` returned by `ArrayList` simply accesses the internal array (without the need to do the repeated range check calls you can see in the `get`-method above

Comment: "As long as you don't synchronize the access to the list, repeated calls of get(index) might actually return different values if between two calls a call of set(index, value) has taken place". No, if you don't synchronize the access, it's most likely that different values *aren't* returned, even if there were another thread that modified the list.

Comment: I didn't say that it's likely to happen only that it can. BTST is an abbreviation for "been there, seen that", i.e. I've actually witnessed this kind of thing in real life. It's very rare but nonetheless possible and very nasty if it actually happens.

Comment: It's a bit of an unclear description. If you're sharing a mutable object between threads, you definitely need to handle synchronization. It's just that if you don't, then it's far more likely that you won't see any difference because a cached value is used. I'm not really sure what point you were trying to make there. Not to mention that concurrency related issues go beyond this question too.

Comment: The description bases on the question where we're talking about a `List<Integer>`. Otherwise you're right, of course, thanks for the clarification. Concerning "beyond the question": The question was "what is better" which is quite broad.